# Error in Google App Engine whenever i restart the system and launch GAE Launcher

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I get this error whenever i restart my system and launch GAE, Sometimes only with fresh installation Of python 2.7.6 and GAE 1.8.2 Or 1.8.7 is working,

```
       2013-11-21 10:34:33 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=7080', '--admin_port=6000', 'C:\\Users\\public\\Desktop\\Course\\f\\coursebuilder']"

        INFO     2013-11-21 10:35:20,766 devappserver2.py:661] Skipping SDK update check.
       WARNING  2013-11-21 10:35:26,089 simple_search_stub.py:1018] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\public\appdata\local\temp\appengine.mazher\search_indexes
       INFO     2013-11-21 10:35:26,178 api_server.py:139] Starting API server at: localhost:52677
      INFO     2013-11-21 10:35:26,188 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: localhost:7080
      INFO     2013-11-21 10:35:26,210 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: localhost:6000
      ERROR    2013-11-21 10:35:39,098 module.py:1150] Internal error while handling warmup request.
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
    File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 1146, in _warmup
request_type=instance.READY_REQUEST)
 File "C:\Program    Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\module.py", line 590, in _handle_request
http_version=http_version)
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 165, in WrappedMethod
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\logservice\logservice_stub.py", line 153, in start_request
host, start_time, method, resource, http_version))
```

OperationalError: database is locked

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and found 4 Python processes running. Killed all of them and relaunched the application - problem solved.